# Equivalent resistance vs Thevenin resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance, thevenin

[image]

What is the difference between equivalent resistance and Thevenin resistance?

Comment: Thevenin resistance is a little more specific about the **method** used to get an equivalent resistance. A Thevenin resistance is always an equivalent resistance. But an equivalent resistance is not always a Thevenin  resistance. It could be a Norton equivalent resistance, for one example.

Comment: Can you please explain the relevance of the schematic to the question?

Comment: It confuses me why getting the Thevenin's resistance starts from right to left and not left to right like I used to. I thought this schematic might help to understand my question. I'm sorry >.<

Comment: There is absolutely no significance to the direction. It will depend on how the schematic is drawn and which points you need the resistance calculated for.

Comment: @walter Do you imagine that the two schematics define the difference between the English phrase "equivalent resistance" and "Thevenin resistance" as if one of those means one phrase and only one and the other of those means the other phrase and only that phrase? Because if so, you are very wrong to think so. The ***only*** difference between those schematics is where you chose to break a wire and make a 2-terminal port there. Which has nothing whatsoever to do in setting boundaries for those two phrases.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think your question is answered in the comments. But I can show why the two resistance meters read different values, this is because:

- Circuit 1:
  $$\text{R}_\text{eq}=4+\left(5\space\text{||}\space9\right)=4+\frac{5\cdot9}{5+9}=\frac{101}{14}\approx7.214\space\Omega\tag1$$
- Circuit 2:
  $$\text{R}_\text{eq}=9+\left(4\space\text{||}\space5\right)=9+\frac{4\cdot5}{4+5}=\frac{101}{9}\approx11.222\space\Omega\tag2$$

Where \$\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\$.